# Is there any way to fill an image with black other than a specific circle in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Can any one help me ? I need to make an image in MATLAB filled with black other than a specific circle i have from a previous function , is that possible ?
Thank you ~

Comment: do you have the coordinates of the circle?

Comment: yes i have , x , y and radius :)

Comment: check the property `(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2 <= r^2`, if this is satisfied then the pixel lies inside the circle otherwise its outside the circle, where (h,k) is the center.

Comment: thank you so much for your help , i'll try it hope it'd work :)

Comment: look at the vectorized solution that I have posted

Answer (score 2):

This is how it can be done:

```
%Center of the circle is (x,y) and radius is r.
x=250;
y=250;
r=50;


%this is your image
a=true(500,500);
for i=1:500
   for j=1:500
      if ((j-x)^2+(i-y)^2)<=r^2 %condition that (x,y) lies on the circle.
         a(i,j)=0;
      end
   end
end
imshow(a)

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Alternate method %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%vectorized way

x=250;
y=250;
r=50;


%this is your image
a=true(500,500);
[x_meshgrid,y_meshgrid]=meshgrid(1:500,1:500);
circle_test=(x_meshgrid-x).^2+(y_meshgrid-y).^2-r.^2;
b=circle_test<=0;
%desiredImage=yourImage.*b;
desiredImage=a.*b;
```

Comment: IT'S WORKING !! IT'S WORKING !! OMG THANKYOU SO MUCH <3333 . I edited it a little bit to get the wanted result and it's perfect now ^^~ Uhh i knew it'd be something like that but couldn't program it since i'm very new to Matlab >< . Thanks again :)

Comment: Please accept/upvote the answer so that it will be useful to other people and it gets off the unanswered question list

Comment: i've tried before but .. "Vote Up requires 15 reputation"

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to render an image (not use the matrix to compute anything afterwards), you can use high level functions like `rectangle` or `viscircles` to draw circles on an image.  Type `'doc rectangle'` in the command window for an explanation of the parameters.  For example:

```
N=50;
x=23; y=11;
rad = 13;

img = zeros(N);

figure(1)
image(im); colormap gray; axis xy; axis image
hold on; rectangle('Position', [x,y,rad,rad], 'Curvature', [1,1], 'facecolor', 'w', 'edgecolor', 'w'); hold off;
```

Comment: Omg this is working too !! Thank you so much <3333 . We've used "rectangle" function in a previous method for drawing the circles !! Thank you thank you ^^